# Omission of Duplicates

Tags: r

Suppose I have the dataset

| ID | Country | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Austria | 3 |
| 1 | Austria | 3 |
| 1 | Austria | 3 |
| 1 | Belgium | 3 |
| 1 | Belgium | 3 |
| 1 | Belgium | 3 |
| 2 | Croatia | 5 |
| 2 | Croatia | 5 |
| 2 | Germany | 5 |
| 2 | US | 5 |
| 2 | US | 5 |

What I want is essentially this as a new dataset:

| ID | Country | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Austria | 3 |
| 1 | Belgium | 3 |
| 2 | Croatia | 5 |
| 2 | Germany | 5 |

1. I only want Austria, Belgium, Croatia and Germany and thus omit the US.
2. See how I removed the duplicates in the countries for each ID: I would like that also.

So in essence, I want to only include certain countries in my dataset, and if there are duplicates in countries with respect to each ID, keep only one of each country (ie. Austria was three, now it is only one).

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
countries_to_keep = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Croatia", "Germany")
your_data |>
  filter(Country %in% countries_to_keep) |>
  distinct()
```

With base R:

```
countries_to_keep = c("Austria", "Belgium", "Croatia", "Germany")
result = your_data[your_data$Country %in% countries_to_keep, ]
result = result[!duplicated(result), ]
```